# Internet not working on Arch Linux OpenVZ

Tags: linux, internet, arch-linux, openvz

I have installed Arch Linux on OpenVZ VPS trought rsync, it's working perfectly but internet is not working.

ip link shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/void
```

I have tried `ip link set venet0 up` for both.

Answer (score 0):

For the most simple network setups, it's usually sufficient to simply do this:

```
systemctl start dhcpcd@venet0.service
```

If that works, then make it permanent like this:

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd@venet0.service
```

This is documented in the [Arch Linux Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide).

---

If the above doesn't work, try this ....

Arch Linux usually uses [NetCtl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl) for setting up networking.

It isn't automatic, but it is relatively easy:

1. Copy `/etc/netctl/examples/ethernet-dhcp` (or `ethernet-static`) into the `/etc/netctl/` directory.
2. Edit the new file, and fill in the details. This should be clear enough.
3. Start the interface with `netctl start ethernet-dhcp`. You might find the interface needs to be set `down` before this will work.
4. If all is well, make it permanent with `netctl enable ethernet-dhcp`. It will now auto-connect at start up.

Other network control tools are available. An alternative you might like to use is [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager), which has an interactive terminal control/configuration tool called `nmtui` (Network Manager Text User Interface).